# My pip install in other PATH and I do not want I do not know how to modify it

Tags: python, path, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a problem that I have been going around for an hour yet I'm sure it's very simple:

my pip installs all the libraries in a `mkdir ~/local/bin` and not in my PATH

I delete it and re-install with `python -m pip uninstall pip`
But nothing to do he always installs me in local

The problem is when I do `pip install jupyter`

jupyter-notebook is not in my Path and when I execute

./jupyter-notebook in local / bin then I have the following answer:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./jupyter-notebook", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>     File "/home_local/isduser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 268, in launch_instance

Answer (score 0):

You are a local user and not an administrator and yuou do not seem to use pyenv or virtualenvs.

pip cannot install anything in the system path as you just don't have the permissions for it.

Therefore pip installs in your local path.

If I recall correctly it should be enough to add (prepend) ~/.local/bin to your search path.

Just type

```
 ls ~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

and check wether the command is found or not.

If the command is not found, then I suggest to use virtualenvs and either direnv or autoenv to activate your virtualenvs.

Tell me whether my first suggestion works. If not, then I'll guide you through virutalenv.

To see if there are already other notebooks running you can type

```
jupyter-notebook list
```

To start the notebook on another port use:

```
jupyter-notebook --port port_number
```